# Epic game launcher "IS NOT A VALID SHORT FILE NAME"

Tags: windows

[image]Hello iam trying to install epic game launcher but i get    "SteamLibrary" is not valid short file name.

I have no idea what "SteamLibrary" got to do with epic game launcher.
When i search in "THIS PC" For " SteamLibrary" i get nothing at all.
I have tried to uninstall epic game launcher with cc cleaner and control panel. But i only get the same massage "SteamLibrary" is not valid short file name"

I have tried to make "new admin user" but still does not work and get the same message.

I have tried to search in "registry editor" Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders

it is set to %USERPROFILE%<username> and not \\profiles$<username> i rly have no idea what to do next.

[image][image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of the error

Comment: any specific screen shots?

Comment: Apparently this error is triggered by values set in the registry at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders`. Check whether it contains a value called `SteamLibrary`.

Comment: Also, please check the [formatting help](https://superuser.com/help/formatting).

Comment: do this screen shot help?

Comment: This is clearly a bug in the MSI for "Epic Games Launcher".  Have you contacted THEM?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - This is not a bug in the Epic Games Launcher, that error, is caused by incorrect syntax within the PATH variable.  The installer created a log, we need that log, to fully debug the actual error on the system.  **This is a system configuration error** It absolutely is not a bug in the installer.

Comment: Try uninstall Discord

Comment: @Ramhound, If it prevented the installer from installing, it was a bug in the installer due to the a condition that the MSI programmer did not anticipate.  I wrote MSI installers for years (for Microsoft).  If a product won't install and doesn't tell you why, it's the installers fault.  I guess we can just differ on opinion here.